# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'foto' cannot be null

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to insert a new image into the database, but I got this error.  Could someone help me please?

Here is my FotoController.php:

```
public function postCreateFoto(Request $request) {

   $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image:jpeg,png,jpg'
   ]);

    $pathName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/upload', $pathName);
    }

    $foto = new Foto([
        'foto' => $request->input('image')
    ]);

    $foto->save();

    return redirect()->route('home');

}
```

Comment: `$request->file('image')`, `$request->input('image')` - now which one is it …?

Comment: @misorude How do you mean?

Comment: I mean, why are you trying to get data for an uploaded file using two different ways? `$request->input('image')` likely doesn’t return anything.

Comment: @misorude If I delete

$foto = new Foto([ 'foto' => $request->input('image')]);

would it work?

Comment: Then you would not have a Foto instance that you could call `save` on afterwards to begin with … No, I meant you should replace `$request->input('image')` in there with `$request->file('image')` – after all, the latter is what you used to access the uploaded file in the lines before this already, so why did you switch to something else here in the first place?

Comment: @misorude I'm sorry, I'm new with Laravel. I don't understand everything yet.